# NewsApi returning totalResults=20 even after specifying pageSize=100

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm using [News API](https://newsapi.org) in android app.

I'm trying to get more results (news) from the server but it is always returning just 20 results which has been set as default as mentioned in the docs [here](https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/top-headlines).

Here's my code:

```
class DownloadNews extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String xml = "";

            String urlParameters = "";
            xml = Function.excuteGet("https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&pageSize=100&apiKey=******************", urlParameters);
            return xml;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final String xml) {

            if (xml != null) {
                if (xml.length() > 10) { // Just checking if not empty

                    Log.d("xml", xml);

                } else {

                }
            } else {

            }
        }

    }
```

I've specified `pageSize` argument as `100` but still I'm getting just `20` `totalResults`:

`09-29 22:29:22.241 10275-10275/com.abc.xyz D/xml: {"status":"ok","totalResults":20,"articles":[]}`

What's going wrong here?

Comment: It could be the API itself having paging problem. Have you tried fetching data via another tool like Postman to see if you get 100 results?

Comment: @DutA. Nope. please tell me more about Postman.

Comment: Postman is an API testing tool. Check it out here: https://getpostman.com/

Comment: I am getting 38 no matter what I set `pageSize` to or `country`

Answer (score 4):

It's the API having a problem. It looks like there are only **20** news items available for '**India**' (if '**in**' stands for that) and that **20** appears to have been hard-coded or the total number of items is being returned regardless of the *pageSize* param.

In [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com), I tried with `pageSize=100` like you did and still got `"totalResults": 20`. I again tried `pageSize=10` and interestingly, `totalResults` remained 20 but got 10 articles back as specified.

Comment: Oh! Is there any other news api you are aware of?

Comment: I haven't used these personally but others mention them being good ones, give them a try:

https://rapidapi.com/contextualwebsearch/api/Web%20Search;

https://webhose.io/products/news-feeds/

Answer (score 4):

The /top-headlines endpoint only returns a max of 20 articles. When an article is no longer considered a 'top headline' it drops off this endpoint. If you need to retrieve more than 20 articles you can use the [/everything endpoint](https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/everything), which includes all top headlines and any other smaller articles too.

Comment: but with `/everything` endpoint I can't specify the country, right? What I want is top 100 headings/articles of India. How can I get them?

Comment: In the doc it says `pageSize int The number of results to return per page (request). 20 is the default, 100 is the maximum.` I never get 100 back, only 38 tested it with country codes us and gb

Answer (score 1):

API's are working fine I have just implemented it, just consider the page as 1,2...so on i.e when you get the first 20records(or as per page size) set your page to 1 and then increment the page 2 for second request.

In swift I have implemented it below

```
    let currentPage = self.articles.count/pageSize
    fetchHeadlines(page: currentPage+1)
```

Hope it helps others!!!!

Comment: Silly, I was making the same mistake"

Answer (score 0):

This is the update I got from NewsApi team

> pageSize isn't a valid param on the top-headlines endpoint. It only
> works on the everything endpoint

Comment: yeah but the problem with `/everything` endpoint is that you can't specify a country with it.

Comment: On page https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/top-headlines `pageSize` is documented as valid parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation from the NewAPI.  I got this after setting the

```
pageSize=100
&page=100
```

This is the outcome.

```
{'status': 'error', 'code': 'maximumResultsReached', 'message': 'You have requested too many results. Developer accounts are limited to a max of 100 results deep. You are trying to request results 9900 to 10000. Please upgrade to a paid plan if you need more results.'}
Error reading
```

This is not a programming issue.

Answer (score 0):

You would better use ContextualWeb NewsAPI. It has better results and much more popular. Also you are not limited to 20 results. Their NewsAPI is the most popular API on the RapidAPI marketplace.

The code can be found here: https://github.com/roikra/newsapi

APIKey can be generated here: https://rapidapi.com/contextualwebsearch/api/web-search

Here is the code:

```sh
public static void Test()
{
    //Required Package: Unirest-API (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unirest-API/)

    //Replace the following string value with your valid X-RapidAPI-Key.
    string Your_X_RapidAPI_Key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    //The query parameters: (update according to your search query)
    string q = "Taylor%20Swift"; //the search query
    int pageNumber = 1; //the number of requested page
    int pageSize = 10; //the size of a page
    bool autoCorrect = true; //autoCorrectspelling
    bool safeSearch = false; //filter results for adult content

    //Perform the web request and get the response
    var response = Unirest.get(string.Format("https://contextualwebsearch-websearch-v1.p.rapidapi.com/api/Search/NewsSearchAPI?q={0}&pageNumber={1}&pageSize={2}&autoCorrect={3}&safeSearch={4}", q, pageNumber, pageSize, autoCorrect, safeSearch))
    .header("X-RapidAPI-Key", Your_X_RapidAPI_Key)
    .asJson<string>();

    //Get the ResponseBody as a JSON
    dynamic jsonBody = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Body);

    //Parse the results

    //Get the numer of items returned
    int totalCount = (int)jsonBody["totalCount"];

    //Get the list of most frequent searches related to the input search query
    List<string> relatedSearch = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(jsonBody["relatedSearch"].ToString());

    //Go over each resulting item
    foreach (var webPage in jsonBody["value"])
    {
        //Get the web page metadata
        string url = webPage["url"].ToString();
        string title = webPage["title"].ToString();
        string description = webPage["description"].ToString();
        string keywords = webPage["keywords"].ToString();
        string provider = webPage["provider"]["name"].ToString();
        DateTime datePublished = DateTime.Parse(webPage["datePublished"].ToString());

        //Get the web page image (if exists)
        string imageUrl = webPage["image"]["url"].ToString(); 
        int imageHeight = (int)webPage["image"]["height"]; 
        int imageWidth = (int)webPage["image"]["width"]; 

        //Get the web page image thumbail (if exists)
        string thumbnail = webPage["image"]["thumbnail"].ToString(); 
        int thumbnailHeight = (int)webPage["image"]["thumbnailHeight"]; 
        int thumbnailidth = (int)webPage["image"]["thumbnailWidth"]; 

        //An example: Output the webpage url, title and published date:
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Url: {0}. Title: {1}. Published Date:{2}.",
        url,
        title,
        datePublished));
    }
}
```

Comment: At this date of comment the free version has 10000 request p/month, roughly 333 per day. Google news api gives 500 free p/day

Answer (score 0):

I have recently finished developing the web scraping part of a [python news api project](https://github.com/mansaluke/newsai) which will allow you to pull data directly from news websites without limits.

To install:

```
pip -q install git+https://github.com/mansaluke/newsai.git
```

Here's an example script:
https://github.com/mansaluke/newsai/blob/master/examples/get_news_data.py

Let me know what you think and enjoy !

Answer (score 0):

[newsapi.org](https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/top-headlines) states:

> **pageSize**(int) : The number of results to return per page (request). 20 is the default, 100 is the maximum.

So whenever you feel like you getting fewer results, despite having indicated that you want more then it means there's just not enough content to return everything.